# Hashcode for 3 int without collisions

Tags: hashcode

Can you help me to find the best way to calculate hashcode for the class that has 3 int params (let say `a`, `b`, `c`) and each param may have values in the predefined range? I mean that `a` should be in some range from `a1` to `a2`, `b` correspondingly from `b1` to `b2` and `c` as you may guess from `c1` to `c2`. All these a1, a2, b1... are constant and known when the hashcode builds. I wish to avoid collisions.

Comment: Well if the three ranges end up with more than 2^32 possible values, it's impossible to avoid collisions. What *are* the ranges?

Comment: assuming that the product of ranges does not exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that total number of variants - product `(a2 - a1) * (b2 - b1) * (c2 - c1)` fits into your hashcode capacity. If you are going to use 32-bit unsigned int, that value should be less than `2^32`.

Start constructing hashcode by picking some initial value `s` (you can pick zero thus effectively omitting the initial value). Then for each param do the following:

1. Multiply current hashcode value by current param range (i.e. `a2 - a1`)
2. Add current *adjusted to range* param value to the hashcode value

For your case of three params the formula is

`((s*(a2 - a1) + (a - a1))*(b2 - b1) + (b - b1))*(c2 - c1) + (c - c1)`

where `s` is optional starting value

**EDIT**

Param value added should be adjusted to its range